# How to change 'Keep alive' settings of gunicorn server in airflow

Tags: airflow

We are using Airflow behind AWS load balancer. Load balancer's timeout is at 60s. We want to change Keep alive of webserver - gunicorn to a number higher than 60s. How to change it ?

After surfing, we found that gunicorn config for airflow is in this path ~/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www/. But not sure how to include gunicorn properties here.

Comment: What is your Airflow Version?

Comment: Our Airflow version is 1.9 Duy

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust your Airflow setting similar to below

```
[webserver]

# Number of seconds the gunicorn webserver waits before timing out on a worker
web_server_worker_timeout = 120
```